# WPF DataGrid seems to ignore IsTabStop setting, when pressing Enter

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a datagrid with quite a few columns. Now normally user can press TAB to cycle between controls in the DataGrid cells. Data grid cells have been set to IsTabStop = false, so it's skipping focusing on the the cell itself and it just falls through until focus is given to an actual control.

This seems to NOT WORK if the user presses Enter because they want to work within that same column. DataGrid will pass the focus to the next cell in the COLUMN, BUT it will also ignore the IsTabStop setting, so it just gives focus to the cell itself not the control inside.

Any ideas how to fix this.

Short example

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="grid1" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Key="coloredBorder">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding A, Mode=OneWay}" Header="A"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="B">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Width="20" Height="20" Style="{DynamicResource coloredBorder}"/>
                                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" SelectedItem="{Binding A, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, ElementName=window}"></ComboBox>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also I have appended the example WPF app for this [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pBrTO26HuImIUwyLdV-Sl7kYFvJs3HLU). To reproduce, clck on one of the comboboxes to give it focus. Pres tab and you'll see that the next combo box gets focus normally. If I added more than one combo box column the combobox to the right would get focus.

BUT if you press enter, the focus would go to the cell below, but it won't then skip the cell and go for the cell content. Instead cell is highlighted.
Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [reply I got on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/e4e00d54-9e48-4fdf-96a0-25621e20dc4f/wpf-datagrid-seems-to-ignore-istabstop-setting-when-pressing-enter?forum=wpf):

I solved this by making an attached property:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace GridTabbing
{
    public class EnterKeySample
    {
        public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        static void ue_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;

            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                ue.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
            }
        }

        private static void ue_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ue = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (ue == null) return;

            ue.Unloaded -= ue_Unloaded;
            ue.PreviewKeyDown -= ue_PreviewKeyDown;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool),
            typeof(EnterKeySample), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsEnabledChanged));

        static void IsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ue = d as FrameworkElement;
            if (ue == null) return;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                ue.Unloaded += ue_Unloaded;
                ue.PreviewKeyDown += ue_PreviewKeyDown;
            }
            else
            {
                ue.PreviewKeyDown -= ue_PreviewKeyDown;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The weird bit is that the only thing this is doing is telling WPF to pass focus DOWN when user presses Enter, which I would have assumed was already happening but obviously isn't.